# How to enable CSRF protection in CodeIgniter 3 and use the `get_csrf_hash()` function?

Tags: php, security, deployment, codeigniter-3, csrf

I am trying to enable CSRF protection in my CodeIgniter 3 application. However, when I try to use the `get_csrf_hash()` function in my view file, it's not returning a value. How can I fix this issue?

When using `$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()` in CodeIgniter 3, only the name attribute value of the CSRF token field is being generated, while the value attribute is not being generated by using `$this->security->get_csrf_hash()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable CSRF protection in your CodeIgniter 3 application, you need to do the following:

1. Open the `config.php` file located in the `application/config/` directory.
2. Set `$config['csrf_protection']` to TRUE to enable CSRF protection:

   `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`
3. Save the `config.php` file.

**Note**
that you need to load the Form Helper and the Security Helper in your controller before you can use the `form_hidden()` function and the `get_csrf_token_name()` and `get_csrf_hash()` functions, respectively:

`$this->load->helper('form');`

`$this->load->helper('security');`